# In perl ensure my hash only contains lat/lon that are more than 30 ft apart

Tags: perl, hash, gps, latitude-longitude

*The EDIT is to ensure that the question is **not** to judge distance... my `gcdist()` routine will do that and THAT routine works (it is left out for brevity) ... it is more the double-`foreach` that I need to do in order to test each `ll` against the other `ll` pair. Is there a better way to compare keys in hash against each other:*

I have a hash that contains the following:

```
my %HASH
$HASH{"38.4486x122.7047"} = 1;
$HASH{"38.4487x122.7049"} = 10;
$HASH{"38.4489x122.7050"} = 14;
$HASH{"38.4491x122.7051"} = 20;
```

This hash is mostly used to ensure that -- down to 4 dec points, I don't have duplicates. What I want to do is now ensure that all those points in the `HASH` are not within 30 ft of each other...(the above is test data so these all may NOT be within 30 ft...but you know what I mean).

I have a routine that gets distance between lat/lon points. But this is the way (clumsily) I would think it out:

```
my %HASH_NEW;
foreach my $_ll_1 (sort {$a cmp $b} keys %HASH)
{
    my ($_la1,$_lo1) = split ("x",$_ll_1);
    my $keep_this_one = 1;
    foreach my $_ll_2 (sort {$a cmp $b} keys %HASH)
    {
        # so we don't compare to the current one in the loop
        next if $_ll_2 eq $_ll_1;

        my ($_la2,$_lo2) = split ("x",$_ll_2);
        if (gcdist([$_la1,$_lo1],[$_la1,$_lo1] < ~30ft)
        {
            $keep_this_one = 0;
            last;
        }

    }
    if ($keep_this_one)
    {
        $HASH_NEW{$_ll_1} = $HASH{$_ll_1};
    }
}

sub gcdist
{
    my $_ll1_arrayref = shift();
    my $_ll2_arrayref = shift();

    # get distance between $_ll1_arrayref and $_ll2_arrayref
    # return it to caller
}
```

Now %HASH_NEW would have contents of %HASH with no ll pairs being within 30 ft ... or am i thinking this wrong?

TIA

Comment: I really can't determine what you're asking here. Have you tried it?

Comment: My question (as i just edited...sorry) was when comparing hashes...is this double-foreach the best way?  AND is this logic missing anything when comparing the two? (the `$keep_this_one` flag is bothering me but i don't know how to optimize beyond it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterating over the list twice is permuting, but that's not what you want. You don't care about the order. The distance between X and Y is the same as the distance between Y and X, there's no reason to calculate it twice. Look at using something like [Algorithm::Combinatorics](http://search.cpan.org/~fxn/Algorithm-Combinatorics-0.27/Combinatorics.pm) to generate your pairs to test.

Past that, dumping the first coordinate that's within a given distance may give poor results. Lets assume 4 points, a b c d, where distances are:

```
a <-> b = 40
a <-> c = 45
a <-> d = 25
b <-> c = 40
b <-> d = 20
c <-> d = 15
```

Iterating over the pairs in order and dumping the coordinate as soon as you are lower than the desired distance 30 would result in:

```
a thrown out; it's 25 from d
b thrown out; it's 20 from d
c thrown out, it's 15 from d
```

While you may prefer to throw out d instead, as the remaining 3 points are valid.

I'd look into iterating over combinations of pairs, calculate & cache distances for all combinations, then start dropping the datapoints with the largest number of close points one at a time until none exceed the desired amount.

Comment: Aah! I misunderstood the question. +1.

Comment: If you voted this question down due to this, please undo your downvote.